# How to hide and show part of a notebook with a button?

Tags: notebooks, slideshows

I need to show the user a part of a notebook only if he clicks on a button (or on a checkbox). For example, the user can proceed only if he answers a question correctly in the notebook! Hope to be clear in the answer, thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use the `CellTag` option to keep track of the cell you want to display. Here is the code:

```
createHiddenCell[buttonText_, cellText_] := Module[
  {cell, cellTag = ToString@Unique[], isHidden = True, modifyCell},
  cell = TextCell[cellText, CellTags -> cellTag];
  modifyCell[] := If[isHidden, CellPrint[cell],
    NotebookLocate[cellTag]; NotebookDelete[]];
  Button[buttonText,
   modifyCell[]; isHidden = ! isHidden
   ]
  ]
```

Usage:

```
createHiddenCell["Do you like Mathematica?", "Thanks!"]
```

It will create a button with text "Do you like Mathematica?". And clicking it will toggle the display of your content in the second argument.

You can modify `cell` variable to create more complicated cell if you want.